# How to reuse facts by means of modules in Alloy

Tags: alloy

I have the following specification in Alloy:

```
sig A {}
sig Q{isA: one A}

fact {
    all c1,c2:Q | c1.isA=c2.isA  => c1=c2   // injective mapping
    all a1:A | some c1:Q | c1.isA=a1   //surjective 
}
```

In my models the above fact repeats similarly between different signature. I tried to factor out it as a separate module so I created a module as below:

```
module library/copy [A,Q]

fact {
    all c1,c2:Q | c1.isA=c2.isA  => c1=c2   // injective mapping
    all a1:A | some c1:Q | c1.isA=a1   //surjective 
}
```

Then I tries to use it as bellow:

```
module family

open library/copy [Person,QP] 
sig Person {} 
sig QP{isA:Person}
run {} for 4
```

but Alloy complains that "The name "isA" cannot be found." in the module.

What is wrong with my approach? and Why alloy complains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my previous answer I tried to address your "similarly between different signature" point, that is, I thought your main goal was to have a module that somehow enforces that there is a field named `isA` in the sig associated with parameter `Q`, and that `isA` is both injective and surjective.  I realize now that what you probably want is reusable predicates that assert that a given binary relation is injective/sujective; this you can achieve in Alloy:

**library/copy.als**

```
module copy [Domain, Range]

pred inj[rel: Domain -> Range] {
  all c1,c2: Domain | c1.rel=c2.rel => c1=c2   // injective mapping
}

pred surj[rel: Domain -> Range] {
  all a1: Range | some c1: Domain | c1.rel=a1   //surjective 
}
```

**family.als**

```
open copy[QP, Person] 
sig Person {} 
sig QP{isA:Person}

fact {
  inj[isA]
  surj[isA]
}

run {} for 4
```

In fact, you can open the built-in `util/relation` module and use the `injective` and `sujective` predicates to achieve the same thing, e.g.:

**family.als**

```
open util/relation
sig Person {} 
sig QP{isA:Person}

fact {
  injective[isA, Person]
  surjective[isA, Person]
}

run {} for 4
```

You can open the `util/relation` file (`File -> Open Sample Models`) and see a different way to implement these two predicates.  You can then even check that your way of asserting injective/surjective is equivalent to the built-in way:

```
open copy[QP, Person]
open util/relation

sig Person {} 
sig QP{isA:Person}

check {
  inj[isA] <=> injective[isA, Person]
  surj[isA] <=> surjective[isA, Person]
} for 4 expect 0 // no counterexample is expected to be found
```

Answer (score 2):

Modules in Alloy are treated as independent units (i.e., a module can access only the stuff defined in that module itself and the modules explicitly opened in that module), so when compiling the "copy" module, `isA` is indeed undefined.  A theoretical solution would be to additionally parametrize the "copy" module by the `isA` relation, but in Alloy module parameters can only be sigs.

A possible solution for your problem would be to define abstract sigs `A` and `Q` in module "copy", and then in other modules define concrete sigs that extend `A` and `Q`, e.g.,

**copy.als**:

```alloy
module library/copy

abstract sig A {}
abstract sig Q {isA: one A}

fact {
   all c1,c2:Q | c1.isA=c2.isA  => c1=c2   // injective mapping
   all a1:A | some c1:Q | c1.isA=a1   //surjective 
}
```

**family.als**:

```alloy
open library/copy 

sig Person extends A {} 
sig QP extends Q {} {
  this.@isA in Person // restrict the content of isA to Person
}

run {} for 4
```

Using inheritance to achieve this kind of code reuse is conceptually not ideal, but in practice is often good enough and I can't think of another way to do it in Alloy.

Comment: Thanks, but above solution is limited in the sense that it is not possible that I define another signature say QP2 and apply the *fact* to QP and QP2; for doing so, it is necessary that QP extends also A as well as Q that is not possible in Alloy!

Comment: That's exactly right, and that's what I thought by "conceptually not ideal".